# UTF-8 buffer cleanup using iconv C++

Tags: unicode, utf-8, iconv

I'm trying to clean a utf-8 encoded buffer using iconv and remove all invalid utf-8 codepoints. Below is my code snippet:

```
iconv_t conv = iconv_open("UTF-8//IGNORE","UTF-8");
iconvctl(conv, ICONV_SET_DISCARD_ILSEQ, &flag);
iconv(conv, &inbuf, &len, &outbuf, &outlen);
iconv_close(conv);
```

I noticed that it is not able to remove code points in range of 0xD800-0xDfff (surrogate pairs) even though these are not valid utf-8 codepoints.

Other invalid codepoints like beyond 0x10FFFF and wrong/broken utf-8 byte sequences are cleaned successfully.

What might be the issue here?

Thanks,

Anurag